# What does $this->pivot return if there are many MtoM links? Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Could you explain how to understand what $this->pivot returns if, in my case, one model uses two intermediate tables that link this model to the other two? There is no way to check on the web server.

I drew an illustration to make it easier to ask the question.

Which will return $this->pivot - - - > PropertyOption or Order

Taken from the github repository, which I am studying and there is no connection between the Sku and Order in reverse order (maybe the author just forgot), I provided in this version, in which it is implemented --> pivot table for both Order and PropertyOption is created

[Illustration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0QTUh.png)

Comment: where is this `getPriceForCount` method called?

Comment: @sumitwadhwa Sorry, I forgot to specify, from the Sku